Threading Issue with DbContext in Azure Functions Using Cosmos DB Provider, and MediatR
I'm using Entity Framework Core with the Cosmos DB provider in Azure Functions, and when two HTTP-triggered functions are invoked simultaneously, I get an exception stating that the DbContext was accessed from another thread.
Here’s my setup:

DbContext is registered and configured using the AddDbContext() method.
A UnitOfWork class uses this DbContext, and it's registered as a scoped service.
Several MediatR RequestHandler classes depend on this UnitOfWork and are registered using the RegisterServicesFromAssembly() method.

Program.cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseCosmos(
                "https://your-cosmosdb-uri",
                "your-cosmosdb-key",
                "your-database-name"
            );
        }, ServiceLifetime.Transient);

        services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

        services.AddMediatR(cfg =>
            cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly)
        );
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

MyFunctions.cs
public class MyFunctions
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public MyFunctions(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    [FunctionName("MyFunctionOne")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RunOne(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] HttpRequest req,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await _mediator.Send(new MyRequest(), cancellationToken);
        return new OkObjectResult(result);
    }

    [FunctionName("MyFunctionTwo")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RunTwo(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get"] HttpRequest req,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await _mediator.Send(new MyRequest(), cancellationToken);
        return new OkObjectResult(result);
    }
}

UnitOfWork.cs
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;
    private readonly MyRepository _repo;
    
    public UnitOfWork(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _repo = new MyRepository(_context);
    }

    public MyRepository ProductRepository { get => _repo; }
}

MyRequestHandler.cs
public class MyRequestHandler : IRequestHandler<MyRequest, MyResponse>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public MyRequestHandler(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public async Task<MyResponse> Handle(MyRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Perform operations using UnitOfWork or any other logic
        await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        // Create and return the response
        return new MyResponse
        {
            Result = $"Processed: {request.Data}"
        };
    }
}

Any insights into the cause of this threading issue?
I’ve explicitly tried both Scoped and Transient lifetimes in the AddDbContext() call, but the problem persists.

This is very likely a Captive Dependency issue (where your DbContext is held captive in an (accidental) singleton and therefore reused across requests). Unfortunately, your question is missing the necessary details to reproduce the issue. I would typically start by registering the DbContext as Scoped rather than Transient. Good chance that while starting the application in the debugger, MS.DI throws an error stating that you "cannot consume scoped service ... from singleton." Either way, one of its consumers is kept alive.

@Steven Thank you for the response, I'm thinking the same way, I followed the stack trace to a certain middleware, sorry I can't share too many details, but I'll give feedback whenever this will be resolved. and also the Transient part is only for debugging purposes.

The problem was caused by a middleware that was registered and added to the pipeline using a single extension method called inside the ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(), it was not registered properly using the ConfigureServices() method.
TLDR - register your dependencies exclusively inside the ConfigureServices() call.
